# Given a truth table, is there a way to know if it's possible to create any/all logic gates?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is it possible to do without brute forcing it?

```
| a | b | out |
---------------
| 0 | 0 |  1 |
| 0 | 1 |  0 |
| 1 | 0 |  1 |
| 1 | 1 |  1 |
```

I managed to bruteforce my way through it and figured that it is possible to implement AND/OR/NOT gates, but it took way too long to figure out. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: If you can make either one of NAND or NOR, you have made a universal gate, so you can make every other logic gate.

Comment: You didn't manage, I'd say. Show how you imagine to implement a NOT gate with this, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You notice that if $a$ is true, then the out is true. Thus you can say that it should be `out = a OR (...)` for some expression in the brackets. This alone takes care of the bottom two rows without affecting the top two rows.

As for the top two rows, we see that those correspond exactly to `NOT b`. So we let that be our bracket, and we get the final expression `out = a OR NOT b` quite quickly.

There is also a way to do this relatively quickly in general. If you have some truth table like yours, then it is quite easy to find the [full disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) of the final column. We begin by looking at each row, and what combination of variables they represent. For instance, the first row represents `NOT a AND NOT b`, and the last column represents `a AND b` (these lines are always the combination of every single variable with `AND`, and with `NOT` put in at appropriate places). Then you just take every single one of these that gives a `1` in the final column, and you `OR` them all together. In our case, this gives us

```
out = (NOT a AND NOT b) OR (a AND NOT b) OR (a AND b)
```

This will always work, and always be correct. Can it be simplified? Probably. Is it easy to simplify? Not always.

Comment: And because we've figured out that we can make the NOT and OR gates, we know we can create the AND gate because
`NOT(a AND b) = NOT a OR not B`
which we can just NOT the output again, to get `a AND b`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it shows how to get a boolean expression from the truth table.

Comment: @integralfx I'm answering a completely different question. I'm telling you how to implement you truth table using the standard logic connectors, while you ask how to make the standard logic connectors using your table. I would delete this answer, but I can't since it's accepted.